# Understanding type definition files in Node JS and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to understand how TypeScript projects resolve the import of modules installed via npm and their type definition files.

As far as I know (and following the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules)), there are two ways TypeScript uses for module resolution :

- With a relative path : It will check then on the current directory if the module files exist (`myModule.js`, `myModule.tsx` and `myModule.d.ts`) or in a directory named `myModule` (containing `index.js`, `index.tsx` and `index.d.ts`)
- With a non-relative path : It will check the import following NodeJS behavior by checking in the `node_modules` folder in the same way it did for the references with relative path, and jumping a directory if not found

So it seems pretty easy to understand. What I don't understand, is how it resolves the **type definition files** when imported using `npm install @types/myModule`. I need to understand this in order to structure correctly my project, and also understand why sometimes my modules / type definitions are not found.

I don't understand how it knows that "the folder in `node_modules/@types/myModule` contains the type definition for `myModule` : Where is stored the information that it must check in that folder ?

**Bonus** : What is the best way to import and manage type definition files ? Is it better to install the `@types` package for the related module, or to download the `file.d.ts` and place it in the module folder in `node_modules`?

Any help and / or references are greatly appreciated.